# get time when user presses the key

Tags: javascript, html, clock

I'll really appreciate it, if someone could help me out, I've been stuck on this problem for a few days, google, and other stackoverflow answers just doesn't seem to help.

I have a web application that has an analog clock, from the clock I need to be able to get the time when the user presses the keyboard and compare that to the time they entered, I can get the time they entered through a form but I'm having trouble understanding how I can get the actual keypress time.

Just to make sure that I'm on the right track, will I be able to put in a for loop into each task page for example:

```
    var i = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < 40; i ++){

         //Add user input from form into an array

         //Add actual key press time in an array


         //Show next task link after the 40 trials are complete

         document.getElementById('nextTask').style.visibility="visible";
         document.getElementById('nextTask').style.display="block";
      }
```

There are 120 trials, in 3 separate tasks.

1 of them has no sound.

The other 2 has sound, but only 50% and 75% of the time a beep will occur and at other times it wont.. (I'm still struggling on that part.. but I'll tackle that later lol.)

One last note, would I be able to run 40 trials using just one webpage, or would I have to create 40 X 3 separate pages, for the whole task.

I created a JSFiddle, I'm still new to the whole idea, so let me know if I've made a mistake. http://jsfiddle.net/StrangeLondoner/ymXeG/

The clock stops after a random number of milliseconds, the two keys to press are s and k.

I'd like to thank you for your time reading this question and hopefully helping me get a solution somehow.

**Finished**

Hey guys, thanks for your input. I thought I'd let you guys know what I did, and if anyone else is searching for a similar answer. It may be a little primitive, but I created an identical counter, and ran simultaneously with the the clock, I know perforamance wise this isn't ideal, but I guess this will have to do until I come up with a better solution. I have to get it working somehow I suppose.

Thanks Anyway. I'll update this if I can somehow find a better solution.

Comment: You can construct a JavaScript `Date` object and get the time from it. Just `var timestamp = new Date().getTime();`

Comment: It's not super-accurate of course.

Comment: @Pointy the problem is I need the time from the clock, since the clock does 1 revolution per 2.5 seconds

Comment: Ah - well you could have your clock log its position on each update, along with a timestamp at that point, and then the keypress handler can check  the time and extrapolate the clock position. Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Get the system clock and do the match to what  your clock indicates.  It will be the most accurate since your clock can lag with system load.  (Of course, so can trying to get the key press, but at least lets minimize the damage.)

Javascript is a bad language for real-time processing.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this bit of jQuery.  It may be useful to what you are doing.

```
$(document).keydown(function(f){

if (f.keycode == 83 || f.keycode == 75) //key codes for s and k
{
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();  // n now equals the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970;
}

doSomethingWithTheTime(n); //Here you would call a function to store or compare your time.

return false;

});
```